# Flexbox css get height 100%

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a column on the right `<IndustryList />`, and I want everything in the other `<div>` containing the `<ParameterAndPostSearch />` and `<SocialPostList />` to extend to the bottom, however I can't get it to extend to bottom even with `height: 100%`. Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the relevant Component from ReactJS code:
**I've heavily simplified anything that shouldn't be of an issue. I'm using Tachyons CSS, but it should be self explanatory (I can add CSS if not)**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='flex'>
            <div className='flex fixed width-235-px height-100'>
                <IndustryList />
            </div>
            <div className='margin-L-235px height-100'> // this height isn't doing anything
                <div className=''>
                    <ParameterAndPostSearch />
                </div>
                <div className='flex'>
                    <SocialPostList />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**The `<SocialPostList />` just for reference:**

```
return (
    <div className='flex'>
        <div className='flex-auto'>
            <h4>Available Parameters:</h4>
            <PostListArray />
            {this.props.allSocialPostsQuery.allSocialPosts.map((socialPost, index) => (
                <SocialPost />
            ))}
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input />
                </form>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='background-black width-350-px height-100'>

        </div>
    </div>
)
```

**Figured it out! Update...**
All the fixed and absolutes were causing scroll bars in areas that shouldn't have them. Also, I went through and mimiced the flexbox layout found here https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/LmYay/ and it helped a ton. So took a while but I fixed it all.

Comment: `height: 100%` will only stretch to the container's value. Are all the parent elements set to full height? That includes `body` and `html`.

Comment: Yes I set those to 100%, no luck though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Tachyon CSS, but this is what is written in the docs:

```
/* Height Percentages - Based off of height of parent */
.h-25 { height: 25%; }
.h-50 { height: 50%; }
.h-75 { height: 75%; }
.h-100 { height: 100%; }
.min-h-100 { min-height: 100%; }

/* Screen Height Percentage */
.vh-25 { height: 25vh; }
.vh-50 { height: 50vh; }
.vh-75 { height: 75vh; }
.vh-100 { height: 100vh; }
```

Make sure every parent element is set to 100 %, have no padding and margin.

Comment: Hello @Ravo10, yes I did write out the height only for your reference so h-100 wasn't obscure. But setting it to vh-100 worked!!!

Comment: @KevinDanikowski yes; that is great!! There is still properly something having padding or margin, or not fully at 100 %, since 100 vh targets the window viewport and not the document if I am not completely wrong.

Comment: I now have a scroll bar which shouldn't be there because I set the 100vh for height, any idea why the scroll bar is there? Trying to look it up now. If you know

Comment: @KevinDanikowski yes! That is because there is proparly padding at the bottom. You could add the CSS property `overflow-y: hidden;`. Make sure your `<meta>` tag is set correct with viewport. Viewport should be set to device-height.

Comment: You're a genius, thank you!!! I put that `overflow-y: hidden` into the body and it worked

Comment: @KevinDanikowski glad I could help! Take a look here for good view-port [instructions](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) if you need it.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski ...And add `overflow-y: auto` or `scroll` to another element, if you want to be able to have scroll enabled; e.g. that flexbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157676/discussion-between-kevin-danikowski-and-ravo10).